# Banned personally but not banned on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have some people who I have banned in my personal account. I also have a Page for a group that I help organize.

What I have discovered is that people who I have banned personally can "like" my Page, and then post to it. Here's the kicker: I was unable to see their posts on my own Page because they are in my personal ban list. It was only through a complicated sequence of events that I discovered their presence on my Page's timeline.

How can I ensure people I have personally banned are also banned from the Page I administrate? Or, at the very least, how I can I know if they are posting to my Page or not?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ban them on your Facebook page separately but as you have blocked them on your personal account their profiles won't show up when you are logged in your personal account.

You have to use facebook as the page by clicking on the cog icon on the menu bar and then select a page to view Facebook as that page. Now go to your Facebook page and ban them on the page.